# What is the safe temperature range for a Core-i5 processor?

Tags: cpu, temperature, intel-core-i5

I have an HP laptop with with a Core-i5 450m processor and an ATI Radeon 5650 1GB graphics card. When I played crysis warhead on my system its temprature went up to 82° c. Is it safe to play games up to this temperature level?

Comment: Is this a laptop or desktop processor? If you know the model number, that would be even more helpful. 82 degrees Celsius or Fahrenheit?

Comment: Pretty sure OP means Celsius.

Comment: core i5 450m laptop and yes it is celcius

Comment: It is safe (although its in lower part of the red zone) but it certainly is not comfortable especially its a laptop. Make sure your vents are unclogged and have enough air space. sometimes its worth buying a notebook rest with extra fans. Playing at max you should be about 65-70 celcius not more

Answer (score 16):

The the absolute max temperature for the Intel Core i5 mobile processor is **105°C**.
*Source: [Intel's datasheet for Intel Core (i3 i5 i7) processors](http://download.intel.com/design/processor/datashts/322812.pdf).*

Comment: I'm confused... at 105C, would the notebook shut off? or would it start throttling and shut off maybe around 20C higher?

Comment: The link is broken

Answer (score 4):

I have run my Intel i5-460M at over 91C and had no problems.
I have an application running in the background at startup [Core temp](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=coretemp&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CC8QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.alcpu.com%2FCoreTemp%2F&ei=BzfTTq6UKIjt0gHBtv1L&usg=AFQjCNGSOa9k11mYqDoozf058ltF0aLQMg) which will turn off my laptop if it reaches 103C. You can change settings so when it reaches any temp above X it will slow down the CPU clock speed.

While playing games I haven't gotten the CPU temp past 80C, Even with maxed out graphics and background stuff running.
I used [Prime95](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=prime%2095&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CCwQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Ffiles.extremeoverclocking.com%2Ffile.php%3Ff%3D103&ei=fTfTTqW2DqjX0QHazJkG&usg=AFQjCNHmaf-S3b1SagcP4-F-C5qH7d1q3g) to get the temp that high.

Answer (score 2):

Intels will shut down or get slower if they get too hot. That's one of the nice things about CPUs. There was another thread on here earlier today about a MacBook reaching 90+ degrees while encoding video.

So I would make the staggering assumption that you're fine, so long as your heatsink has the correct contact with your CPU, your fans are all operational, and your case (or laptop) has good airflow.

EDIT:

Here's an [article](http://www.legitreviews.com/article/1060/5/) about a Core i5 reaching 91.

Answer (score 2):

HP DV4-2170us i5 430m (integrated graphics) running Ubuntu 10.04 and have been using for 9 months, idle at 55 C and heavy video export / conversion using openshot 80 C.

Cleaned up the CPU and nearby heat-sinked chip (not sure if its the graphic), and added shim to unknown chip since the thermal pad seemed to be loose (most likely my only temperature reading is from the Cpu it self).

I also mixed a drop of synthetic motorcycle oil with white silicon thermal compound.

Resulting mixure was very thin and I applied only a small thin drop.
CPU now idles at 41 C. and peaks at 70 C for heavy video conversion.

P.S. I previously spilled liquid on my laptop and killed it. I had to clean the motherboard with a toothbrush and replace input power MOSFET 4405.

Answer (score 1):

You have to look at you CPU Detail Specification which can found at [ark.intel.com](http://ark.intel.com) for example you have an [Intel i5-2467M](http://ark.intel.com/de/products/56858/Intel-Core-i5-2467M-Processor-3M-Cache-up-to-2_30-GHz?q=2467) CPU, got to the table with heading "Formatspezifikationen" (German) or "Package Specifications" (Englisch). There you find the parameter "TJUNCTION" with the maximum tempature value for your cpu.

Description of the T-Junction Parameter:
(German): „T JUNCTION“ bezeichnet die maximal zugelassene Temperatur beim Prozessor-Chip.
(Englisch): Junction Temperature is the maximum temperature allowed at the processor die.

Answer (score 1):

My opinion about the question "safe" would rather concern to CPU **estimated lifetime** as a function of temperature.

I don't about **statistics** nor serious studies (if someone does, please report) about it. So, even when SuperUser is not a opinion site, I would say this question has no answer but the **subjective** ones.

As a Technology Engineer, [here](https://superuser.com/questions/749146/safe-long-term-cpu-temp/749172#749172) are all details about mine, for those interested.