# Acceptable Intel i5 Proccessor Temperature?

Tags: core, temperature

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the safe temperature range for a Core-i5 processor?](https://superuser.com/questions/218243/what-is-the-safe-temperature-range-for-a-core-i5-processor)

I'm just wondering if my processor I working under an acceptable temp. From what I have read 42 is pretty decent under idle conditions. But looking as Intel Extreme Tuning its appears red while every thing else is blue. Any suggestions?

[image]

Comment: What is you're specific i5 model?

Comment: It looks like it is a bug with the reading. Does it say 429 Million degrees?

Comment: Hotter than the photoshphere of the sun - decent! :]

Comment: Idle temperatures are basically meaningless. They just measure how much the fan is able to slow down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The i5 should be able to operate at approx. 90 ish... see [this](https://superuser.com/questions/218243/what-is-the-safe-temperature-range-for-a-core-i5-processor) question.

Answer (score 2):

Your temperature monitor is off. You may just be missing a decimal point to get to the real temperature, but as of now, it seems to think that your processor is about half a billion degrees centigrade. That puts it just slighly out of normal bounds.

Your voltage meter is off also.