# Geforce GTX 960M Temperature

Tags: temperature, nvidia-geforce

I am using hashcat on a laptop with Nvidia 960m GPU. Everything is good. Monitoring the GPU temperature I noticed it doesn't go above 73c. Which from reading around it sounds like  normal under heavy usage. 
My question how long can I put the GPU under such utilization before i can cause harm to it. 
Its utilizing 99% of its processing power

Comment: Processors are intended to be used 100%.  Why do you think using it to it's fullest would damage it?

Comment: Yeah but I was wondering about the temperature :)

Comment: As long as you keep it cool, you can run it at 100% until it rusts. :)  Regarding temperature, your question is unclear -- What about it?

Comment: Running at 73c for hours.. All posts I read they say this is okish but would that be okay for long hours. Like 5-7 hours for example ?

Comment: As said: as long as you keep it cool enough to prevent overheating, you can run it for months, years or beyond.  If your research has shown that 73 degrees is acceptable for your specific GPU in your specific machine, then you should be good to go.

Comment: [Might be](http://superuser.com/a/749172/400355) helpgul.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the [NVIDIA web page](http://www.geforce.com/hardware/notebook-gpus/geforce-gtx-960m/specifications) for the 960m, there doesn't appear to be a listed max operating temperature. From some light Googling, it would seem that 73c is perfectly normal. You'll want to start worrying when you're running at 90-100c, especially on battery power, when the system throttles the device to save power.

As Techie007 has mentioned, you can run the card until it rusts at 73c.