# What is a safe running temperature for a CPU while running BOINC?

Tags: cpu, overheating, boinc

I’m running BOINC Manager on my iMac, allowing it to use the full processor. I’m just running SETI@Home, though considering other projects.

I’ve downloaded iStat Menus to monitor it, and I’m noticing my CPU cores are each running around 200°F (93°C). I gather that’s not unusual if a CPU is under heavy load, but my question is whether this is sustainable.

If I leave BOINC running all the time, will it significantly decrease my CPU’s lifespan? If so, what can I do that would make this a safer process?

For example, is there a temperature at which CPUs won’t get damaged? (I could regulate how much CPU time BOINC can use, for  example.)

Comment: Which project(s) are you running on BOINC? They should have computing preferences where you can limit the CPU usage. I run Rosetta@home and set it to 50% and temps are okay

Comment: Ah, thanks. I’m running SETi@Home. I’ll add that via an edit.

Comment: Okay yeah I ran that too, it should have the same exact settings. `Computing preferences` under Your Account page

Comment: I know comments aren't for discussion, but which team do you compute for? Got a link to your boincstats page?

Comment: It all depends on your system, environment and resources. If you are concerned just tweak to lower usage.

Answer (score 1):

You can manage the usage of all resources used by BOINC. The example here is SETI@Home but I think it's identical or similar for others. I run Rosetta@Home and it looks the same.

Under the **Your account page**, go to **Preferences** → **Computing preferences**.

[image: Your account]

Scroll to the bottom and click the green **Edit preferences** button. Now you should be able to edit all of the values.

Change the CPU time to 50% or whatever suits your system. I use 40% and get reasonable temps. If you hover over the box, it gives you an explanation of the usage.

[image: Computing preferences]

In BOINC Manager you'll have to update the project. It should then reflect these changes.

Comment: Thanks. I guess my question is more to do with how you determined what suited your system, what reasonable temperatures meant for you. Possibly running four cores at 200°F isn’t a problem, but I just don’t know. And I don’t know if 50° is any better, for that matter. Do you have any recommendations for where to find out about this?

Comment: Ah, that's very subjective then. There have been many questions about that, often closed as off-topic https://superuser.com/questions/749146/safe-long-term-cpu-temp