# GA-Z170N-Gaming 5 what are normal CPU teperatures

Tags: cpu, motherboard, fan, cooling, temperature

My CPU fan recently came loose and all the thermal paste is dry(the fan isnt really snapped or glued on anymore) So naturally, my CPU is heating up fairly quickly. While I do plan on replacing the CPU fan, in the mean time I decided to monitor it using a little program called [Core Temp](https://www.alcpu.com/CoreTempMB)

What I want to know is what would average CPU temperatures be under full load? I mean, yes of course this is going to vary on many things, like how many apps are running and the drain on the CPU. It should be known I like to run this thing heavy (games, 3ds max, Google Chrome with lots of open tabs, Photoshop all at once). Before the CPU fan gave out this was fine and my machine was ok. I am running an Intel i5-6500 quad core on a GA-Z170N-Gaming 5 motherboard, with 24 gigs of ram an Nvidia GTX-970 for GPU.

After the CPU fan issue just running a video game and having 3ds Max open will put me upwards of 90 degrees with the maximum temperature value being at 98 or so before going critical or shutdown. Id like to know what the target or normal ranges would be once I get the CPU fan back to normal

Comment: Questions regarding CPU temps are often subjective and closed as opinion-based (e.g. https://superuser.com/questions/749146/safe-long-term-cpu-temp). You can find information in that related question though. For me, idle temps are usually around 40C and under full load 80C. I would not recommend running higher than 90C for an extended period of time.

Comment: Temp. ranges will also vary a lot on not mentioned conditions. E.g. How warm is the room?  Which CPU fan are you using (assuming the stock supplied one here, but an aftermarket cooler can really change things).  How warm is the air inside the desktop?  etc etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I did some digging around and found [this site](https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000687.ht) which explains average temperatures for CPUs according to make and model.

***"The majority of today's desktop processors should not exceed temperatures of 45-50°C when idle, or 80°C when under full load. Below is a chart listing many types of processors and their average temperatures under full load."***

This is a very handy resource for anyone wanting to know average temperatures under a full load, or even just idle.

In my case, the Intel i5 says that 50°C - 62°C is the average temp under full load.

I hope this resource is helpful to anyone out there. 
Thanks!